# getting permission denied when i "ls" into mounted gcp bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, mount, gcsfuse

using this bash command to mount the bucket.

```
mkdir /tmp/gcpbucketname-full && gcsfuse --implicit-dirs gcpbucketname /tmp/gcpbucketname-full/
```

the bucket mounts successfully -

Yet I get permission denied when running `ls /tmp/ml-9a0d-phi-shared-aif-us-p-full/`

> ls: reading directory '/tmp/gcpbucketname-full/': Permission denied

Is there a permissions missing?

Comment: Permissions seem the issue.  On which platform are you mounting the bucket? Your computer? on GCE? Elsewhere? What the current permissions of your current credential? You can also add the parameter `--debug_gcs` to gcsfuse to have more debug info

Comment: on a compute instance - current permissions i'll check the permissions. thx